# Adding functionality to Symfony2 entities

Tags: symfony

I am confused about how to go about adding functionality to my entities.

Say I have a table of fee increases. My database table has these fields

- company_id
- date
- amount

and I've made the corresponding `FeeIncrease` entity in my Symfony2 project.

Now, for one part of my application, I need to display an `HTML` table of all fee increases occurring in a particular month. The table will contain all the fields from the database table, but will also contain one additional field: the previous fee amount. Something like this:

```
company_id | date       | amount | previous_amount
-----------+------------+--------+----------------
1          | 2013-02-03 | 500    | 400
3          | 2013-02-15 | 1000   | 800
8          | 2013-02-20 | 1100   | 500
```

Thinking about it from the database angle, each row will require a subquery that selects the latest fee increase from the table (i.e. it queries for the fee increase with the latest date before the date of the current increase).

Currently I'm writing out the subquery using [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html), but already the complexity of the business logic is making it clear that this isn't a long-term solution. Different pages will require different 'where' clauses, so I'll be writing a new query for each page. Also, there is more logic that needs to be applied to the fields themselves, and I would prefer to have this logic encapsulated within some other object, rather than having it float around my controllers and views, as it is now.

**My question is, essentially, how can I add extra properties that depend on entity data to my entities?**

Ideally, I would add a `$previousAmount` property to my `FeeIncrease` entity. `getPreviousAmount` would be a method that did the complex query for me. But how can I add this method and have it leverage Doctrine's functionality? For example, say I use `->findAll()` to get an array of fee increases. Then, in my template, I iterate through the array, but for each fee increase I display the previous amount:

```
{% for feeIncrease in feeIncreases %}
  {{ feeInrease.previousAmount }}
{% endfor %}
```

This would result in another database call, for each increase. This would be unusable in my case, given the number of fee increases I want to display.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

The fee increases I've described above are associated with contracts. Each contract has many fee increases. For every month, each contract has a 'current' fee, which is found by the following rules:

- If a contract has a new fee increase starting that month, use that amount.
- If a contract has a fee increase ending that month, and not another one following up, use that amount.

There are other rules. So my question is, where can I put these rules, so that when I'm actually working with my `contract` and `feeIncrease` objects, I can use methods like `contract.currentFee` without having to add all of this logic everywhere?

Comment: Why can't you save `previous_amount` as a field?

Comment: I don't have control of the database. There are also several other cases where I require this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) that is coupled with your entity: in that way you keep all sql (or DQL or query builder) in the same place, and you can even parametrize it.
One advantage of this method is that you can even fetch *ALL DATA* with same query, and use returned values into twig template without demand retrive action to doctrine's lazy loading facility.

So you will have an entity like `FeeIncrease`

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="FeeIncrease")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\BundleNameBundle\Repository\FeeIncreaseRepository")
*/

class FeeIncrease
{
  [...]
}
```

where you specify repository location and, then, you create your repository in that way

```
//Company\BundleNameBundle\Repository\FeeeIncreaseRepository
<?php

namespace Company\BundleNameBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * FeeIncreaseRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */

class FeeIncreaseRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function myCostumQuery($paramers)
  {
    //your own logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now. The parameters may help out a bit, but there is still a lot of logic that I don't want to leave in my controller. I'm really looking for how to make a new object that uses entity data.

Comment: @SamSelikoff: What logic? Without code is very difficult. What I can suggest to you, is to make a service, migrate all Business Logic in it and use Repositories for query. Is the best way to procede

Comment: I added a bit of code. I don't know much about services, so I think I should learn more about them. Thanks for your help so far. Maybe my code will make my problem a bit clearer.